# How to insert newline between elements being formed through a while loop?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a newline or you can say, br tag between elements which are being created with a while loop.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div id = "demo">
</div>
```

**Here is my Javascript**

```
        var parent_div = document.getElementById("demo")
        var new_para = document.createElement("p")
        var br = document.createElement("br");

        var number = 10;

        while(number < 21){

            var t = document.createTextNode("Hello" + " " + number)
            new_para.appendChild(t)
            

            parent_div.appendChild(new_para)
            parent_div.appendChild(br)

            number ++
        }
```

**Currently, I get the result as**

```
Hello 10Hello 11.....
```

**However, I was expecting this result**

```
Hello 10
Hello 11 
....
```

Kindly help me in fixing the issue.
Thnanks in advance

Comment: where is HTML? It would be easier to understand if you could include HTML also?

Comment: HTML contains an empt div with "demo" tag. I will include it now.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks. I placed the br element creating line in my while loop and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the text in the same `p` element. So you can create new `p` every time you add the text.

So no need to use `br` here also. `p` tag will do everything perfectly.

```js
var parent_div = document.getElementById("demo")
var number = 10;

while (number < 21) {
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello" + " " + number)

  var new_para = document.createElement("p") // change
  new_para.appendChild(t)

  parent_div.appendChild(new_para)

  number++
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You. This works like a charm. I also tried placing the br element creating line in my while loop and appended it in paragraph tag.

Comment: That totally depends on you how you want, First one is a bunch of paragraphs without `br` and the second is a bunch of `br` in a `p` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a `br` tag to the `paragraph` instead of putting it in the `parent_div` and, finally, append the `paragraph` to the `parent_div` only once, after the while loop.

```js
var parent_div = document.getElementById("demo")
var new_para = document.createElement("p")

var number = 10;

while(number < 21){

    var t = document.createTextNode("Hello" + " " + number)
    new_para.appendChild(t)
    
    var br = document.createElement("br")
    new_para.appendChild(br)

    number ++
}

parent_div.appendChild(new_para)
```

```html
<div id="demo"/>
```